# How to sort list by numbers saved in firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I have a list of characters that I load from Google firestore.  Everything loads correctly.  I want to sort the list by the characters power.  I'm trying this:

```
db.collection("Characters").orderBy("POWER")
```

It sorts the list but not correctly.  I have numbers ranging from 100 to 25000.  What I end up with is something like this: 
100
1000
200
25000
3
35

What I want is this:
3
35
100
200
1000
25000

Comment: can you share the data here ?

Comment: it looks like you have  string stored in Power not numbers.

Comment: Your right.  I didn't even realize I saved it like that.  Fixed that and it now sorts correctly.  Thank you.

Comment: oh good to know that , just read , i even answered it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing it as String in firestore , store it as number it will work.
if power comes from textbox while saving parse it to number,like Number('123').

Hope this helps